# How to change SENSOR_ORIENTATION to a non deprecated code and run this code

Tags: android, orientation, accelerometer, deprecated

I made this code that I found in a tutorial and made a few changes. That code shows the orientation and accelerometer sensor and when the smartphone changes 45° degrees it counts the number of curves. It works perfectly.  But I saw that SENSOR_ORIENTATION,SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER were deprecated. How can I change my code using non deprecated constants and keep it working? I am beginner on android programming and in stack overflow. Thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorListener {
    private long lastUpdate=0;
     private float last_x = 0;
     final String tag = "IBMEyes";
    SensorManager sm = null;
     TextView xViewA = null;
     TextView yViewA = null;
     TextView zViewA = null;
     TextView xViewO = null;
     TextView yViewO = null;
     TextView zViewO = null;
     TextView mud=null;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     xViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xbox);
     yViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ybox);
     zViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zbox);
     xViewO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xboxo);
     yViewO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yboxo);
     zViewO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zboxo);
     mud=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.mud); 
       }
     static int cont =0;
     //se (valor_INICIAL - VALOR_ATUAL) > 45
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
      synchronized (this) {
      Log.d(tag, "onSensorChanged: " + sensor + ", x: " +
    values[0] + ", y: " + values[1] + ", z: " + values[2]);
      if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION) {
      xViewO.setText("Orientation X: " + values[0]);
       yViewO.setText("Orientation Y: " + values[1]);
       zViewO.setText("Orientation Z: " + values[2]);
       double diffDegree = Math.abs(values[0] - last_x);
       if (diffDegree > 45)
        {
          last_x = values[0];
         mud.setText("cont: "+ ++cont);                 
        }
          }
        }
       if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {
       xViewA.setText("Accel X: " + values[0]);
      yViewA.setText("Accel Y: " + values[1]);
       zViewA.setText("Accel Z: " + values[2]);
       }
      }
       private void setText(string mud) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
      protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
     // register this class as a listener for the orientation and accelerometer sensors
      sm.registerListener(this,
      SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION |SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER,
      SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            // unregister listener
            sm.unregisterListener(this);
            super.onStop();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    }
        @Override
     public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy) {
        Log.d(tag,"onAccuracyChanged: " + sensor + ", accuracy: " + accuracy);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to refer to a sensor, use: [Sensor.TYPE_XXXX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html). For instance: Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER & Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION.

I don't know if it's needed or not, but you might want to check if "sm" is null in onResume().
Additionally, you probably want to unregister the SensorEventListener in onPause() rather than onStop().

Comment: But TYPE_ORIENTATION is deprecated too. Eclipse recommends to use getOrientation() but I couldn't use it in my code. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: That's news to me. Looks like it's deprecated as of api 20, which is  currently hardly even in use. You can still use it or another similar sensor like rotation. You can probably also calculate it yourself with accelerometer and magnetic field